# How to binary image to labelimage in itk

Tags: python, image, label, itk

I try to analysis a image which was binarized with threshold filter, actually split image into two parts (they all include apart of the boundary). then I would like to convert this image into a label image (binary image - label map - label image) and then analysis by label.

```
LabelFilter0 = itk.BinaryImageToLabelMapFilter.IUC3LM3.New()
LabelFilter0.SetInput(BinaryFilter.GetOutput())
LabelFilter0.SetInputForegroundValue(100)
LabelFilter0.SetFullyConnected(False)
print LabelFilter0.GetNumberOfObjects()
LabelImage0 = itk.LabelMapToLabelImageFilter.LM3IUC3.New()
LabelImage0.SetInput(LabelFilter0.GetOutput())
Sta0Filter = itk.LabelStatisticsImageFilter.ISS3IUC3.New()
Sta0Filter.SetLabelInput(reader1.GetOutput())
Sta0Filter.SetInput(reader0.GetOutput())
```

However no object could be found after itk.BinaryImageToLabelMapFilter . I totally got lost what should i do to set this filter?

[image: this is the image I would like to analysis]

Here is the 3D data after threshold:

> https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6iiB8fojky9NXhOZXFVWTNIbHlLc01jdmFyT2FkdDVmdXFB/edit?usp=sharing 
>  
>   https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6iiB8fojky9dnlSSmNqOHk4NDM1WHRBLVRhWWpHLUxGZ1JF/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

An example of how to use the LabelStatisticsImageFilter can be found in ITK Examples page [here](http://www.itk.org/Wiki/ITK/Examples/ImageProcessing/LabelStatisticsImageFilter). It's in C++, but the idea is the same and looks something like:

```
typedef itk::BinaryImageToLabelMapFilter<ImageType> BinaryImageToLabelMapFilterType;
BinaryImageToLabelMapFilterType::Pointer binaryImageToLabelMapFilter = BinaryImageToLabelMapFilterType::New();
binaryImageToLabelMapFilter->SetInput(image);
binaryImageToLabelMapFilter->Update();

typedef itk::LabelMapToLabelImageFilter<BinaryImageToLabelMapFilterType::OutputImageType, ImageType> LabelMapToLabelImageFilterType;
LabelMapToLabelImageFilterType::Pointer labelMapToLabelImageFilter = LabelMapToLabelImageFilterType::New();
labelMapToLabelImageFilter->SetInput(binaryImageToLabelMapFilter->GetOutput());
labelMapToLabelImageFilter->Update();

typedef itk::LabelStatisticsImageFilter< ImageType, ImageType > LabelStatisticsImageFilterType;
LabelStatisticsImageFilterType::Pointer labelStatisticsImageFilter = LabelStatisticsImageFilterType::New();
labelStatisticsImageFilter->SetLabelInput( labelMapToLabelImageFilter->GetOutput() );
labelStatisticsImageFilter->SetInput(image);
labelStatisticsImageFilter->Update();
```

In your code I don't see the 'Update' calls you need to trigger the start of the pipeline. You might want to check that first.

My experience with this filter was that you could attach this filter directly to the end of the BinaryThresholdImageFilter to use it.